# Why do we need Trigonometry in calculus ? Why Calculus textbooks are incomplete without Trigonometry?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, soft-question

I started learning mathematics in my 30's , i just got interested in mathematics and want to understand math deeply for long terms point of view.

While reading calculus textbook, a question came to my mind !

**So my question is "Why do we need Trigonometry in calculus ? Calculus textbooks are incomplete without Trigonometry equations and functions ? What's the deep meaning behind using Trigonometry in calculus textbook or calculus real life application use in engineering and science ? How it(trig) in calculus help us humans solving the real life engineering problems and innovations.**

If anyone knows the answer then please let me know. If you know any resources which can help me to find the answer of my question then please share the link or book name.

Thank You

Comment: There are plenty of calculus texts without trigonometry in them, many for business students. Trigonometric functions are all over engineering and physics as solutions to simple, important differential equations, so it is often included for future use.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I want to understand calculus from the point of view of using it in engineering applications or the application of robotics or Drone AI development.

Comment: So you are saying we need Trig in calculus to solve differential equations ? Like saying Trig is like a friend which helps us to solve differential equations , just like algebraic identities help us to simplify difficult algebraic expression to find solutions.

Comment: Your question is so broad that I doubt you'll get a satisfactory answer. Surveying the topic on the web can provide you with various **angles** (an important word for trigonometry!). [Real-life applications of trigonometry](https://www.mathnasium.com/blog/real-life-applications-of-trigonometry) can be a good start. Or [History of trignonometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_trigonometry)... and many others.

Comment: Thank You. Yes you are right about the broad nature of my question. I did google to find the answer of my question but non of the answer on google exist from the point of view of "Trig in Calculus".

Comment: Circular motion is all over the place in engineering and science. Objects in circular motion are described using trigonometric functions, and their velocities and accelerations are described using derivatives of trigonometric functions.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your answer makes sense. But what if the "Object" is continuously changing it's position like drone in forest ? I also saw lot's of calculus in probability and statistics textbooks, so your answer is also useful from the POV of calculus in probability ?

Comment: You need at least be familiar with elementary trigonometry because of the importance of **Fourier series and Fourier transform** which are central in analysis.

Comment: Thanks @JeanMarie. Is Fourier series and Fourier transform is also Important in calculus 2 and calculus 3 ? And when should someone starts learning Analysis after calculus 1 or after calculus 1, 2, 3 ?

Comment: "calculus 1" and "2" are part of "Analysis"...

Comment: @JeanMarie ohh thank you. I read in one of the google page where someone said that you study Analysis in Graduate or post graduate courses and it comes after calculus.

Comment: "Calculus" is a term which is used in Anglo-saxon educational systems to encompass the first levels of analysis ; it has no equivalent for example in French educational system (we don't say "I must first pass my "calcul différential et intégral 1 et 2" before I learn more about analysis). I think in german, spanish, italian systems it is similar. I mention it because of the almost-magic attached to this word "Calculus" (strange that there is no "Calculus wand" in Harry Potter : if you are hit by it, you become instantly proficient in analysis...).

Comment: @JeanMarie thank you for this information about french educational system things about calculus.

Answer (score 4):

I think there are two practical issues on this.

The first is that Calculus comes *after* trigonometry in most curricula.  Therefore, if a calculus course did *not* include derivatives/integrals of sine and cosine functions, when would the students learn them?  They can't teach these *in* trigonometry class (where it might make more sense) because the students there have not learned calculus!

The second reason is that some of the techniques to solve integrals of non-trigonometric functions *utilize* trigonometry functions to solve them.  Trigonometric substitution is a *very* common technique for integrating, which is used on formulas which don't themselves involve any trigonometric functions.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. After going through many answers on my questions i came to conclusion that Trigonometry is like a tool which helps us to solve /approximate difficult calculus questions related to a movable object in reality / motion. Am I right ?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!
Trigonometry is ubiquitous in calculus. You can **technically** learn most fundamental calculus concepts without any knowledge of it, but trigonometric functions arise probably in every possible application of calculus. Besides, trigonometric functions have many nice properties and provide good examples.

You don't really need to know the trigonometry as a whole, though. All you really need in most of the cases is definitions of $\sin$, $\cos$, $\tan$ and $\cot$ functions, their geometrical meaning, and a few basic formulae that connect them, like fundamental theorem of trigonometry, double angle/ half angle formulae and what happens if you substitute $x\to x+\pi /2$ into a trigonometric function. These specific facts are used everywhere, the rest is mostly technical stuff you will rarely encounter, if at all.

Now, to the common applications of trigonometry in calculus problems:

1. The limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ is extremely important in physics and engineering, for instance, because it allows you to linearize the pendulum equation. If you write down the Newton's equation for the pendulum, you will realize that the resultant force that acts on a mathematical pendulum is proportional to the sine of angle of deviation from the vertical. This results in a complex nonlinear differential equation which can only be solved using non-elementary functions ("elliptic integrals"). However, if the deviation angle is small, thanks to the limit $\sin x/ x$ you can approximate the sine of the angle with the angle itself, and obtain a linear differential equation, the solutions of which are trigonometric functions (harmonic oscillations, sines and cosines). And harmonic oscillator is probably the single most important object in all of physics. As one quantum field theory textbook puts it, "The career of a young theoretical physicist consists of treating the harmonic oscillator in ever-increasing levels of abstraction".
2. Geometric optics is impossible without trigonometry. For instance, you use trigonometric functions every time you evaluate the length of a complex optic path.
3. Fourier analysis is used in every field of science extensively, since it allows one to represent (almost) all periodic processes as linear combinations of harmonic (i.e. sinusoidal) oscillations, and analyze each problem for each harmonic oscillation individually, as if no other existed. A canonical example is sound equalizing and filtering, where you can decompose a sound into individual frequencies and then manipulate them. Other ur-examples include circuit analysis for alternating current circuits and solving the heat equation (and other equations of mathematical physics, for instance, the wave equation).
4. Using trigonometric functions, you can define angles in very abstract spaces which have a certain additional structure in them. For instance, in computer linguistics it is a common technique to represent words as vectors in a certain abstract space, and then the angle between these words can show the degree of their similarity.
5. There are generalizations of trigonometry for different structures of the space being analyzed (as opposed to the Euclidean space). Spherical trigonometry is useful in observational astronomy, and hyperbolic trigonometry alleviates the understanding of special relativity.

Comment: Thank You for your Beautiful answer. So the deep meaning of Trigonometry use in calculus also changes as per the different area of science field ? How much Trigonometry you think is more than enough for understanding calculus 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Exactly the definitions and properties of trigonometric functions I described.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I am a PhD student in Group Theory (a branch of Algebra), but I think I can give you a bit of persepctive about the topic. First of all, from a historical point of view, all Math came from Geometry! From the book *The Elements* of Euclides to *Principia Mathematica* of Isaac Newton, all derived from things that they observed, therefore, all their results came ultimately from Geometry.

It is true that Calculs can exists outside Geometry, but Calculus is, in essence, the study of things when it tends to some limit and the study of precise approximations, which, again, firstly came from Geometry, since to approximate something it need to be measured.

Nevertheless, it is only my humble opinion of the topic, and I would like to know what do you think about it and, if you do not mind, I also would like to know what is your background.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My background is Bachelor of Mass Media in Advertising & Marketing. Failed movies script writer (Bollywood) and currently learning Machine Learning since last 2 years. So I don't have problems with Imagination and creativity but I have a problem with mathematics. My mind works differently. So to bring my imagination into reality with the help of Artificial Intelligence, I have to understand mathematics deeply so that I can convert my imagination into math equation and then finally AI algorithms. I just want to understand things deeply. Thank You

Comment: So you are saying -> First Geometry then ---> Trigonometry then ----> Calculus ?    If we can't find the answer from the use of Geometry then we should use Trigonometry and if Geometry and Trigonometry can't be used to find approximate solutions of movable things in reality then we can use the Trigonometry as tool in calculus to find Approximate solution instead of exact solution ?

Comment: Hello again @ShashankSureshShahi. I am not saying that first it comes Geometry, then Trigonometry and then Calculus. I am basically saying that, at least historically, all Math started from Geometry. If you want to undertand this concepts a bit more abstractly, in my opinion you should undertand Math as "equalities of things", and different ways to undertand those equalities leads to different "branches of Math".

Comment: @ShashankSureshShahi Regarding your initial question, if you are starting to study calculus for the first time, it would feel more natural to know why some definitions are how they are. For instance, imagine you want to study derivaties, and they show you directly the "formula of the derivative". That would probable mean nothing to you, because you do not know the propuse or the reason of the expresion, whereas I they show how why the formula is defined that way, you would probable feel it more reasonable. That is why I think many calculus books start with some Geometry lessons.

Comment: Thanks @José Gálvez Mateos for giving your time for answering the question. As you said you are doing PhD in mathematics. So my question to you "How do you read and understand difficult mathematics textbook on your own ? " and "Why the mathematics textbooks are written the way they are written ? " As a PhD student for you it must be easy to understand any maths textbook ? Am i right ?

Comment: @ShashankSureshShahi Well, it depends on the topic you are reading. I am more familiariced with algebra topic in general, whereas I will probably fill lost with advanced topic about analysis or stadistcs. And another thing you should know is that when you try to research about something, usually you want to know what the people who study similar things is doing, so when you look for information you search mostly for articles and not that much in books.

Comment: That been said, I answer your two questions. When a read math articles, depending on how familiariced I am with the topic, I usually take some time to work on examples (in case that those examples are computables haha). Regarding why Math books are written that way, I do not know in general. The majority of the textbooks I have read are written constructively, that is, you start with ideas, from that you define what you are going to do, and then you start to build the topic. The same structure plays the role in articles, just a bit more quick due to the lenght availeable.

Comment: Galvex Mateos, thanks for your answer.